# `empty',`<|>' : not a (visible) method of class `Alternative'

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a parser in Haskell, but I'm having issues with the Alternative definition of it ( Functor, Applicative and Monad are done and working ):

```
instance Alternative Parser where
empty = P (\env input -> [])
p <|> q = P (\env input -> case parse p env input of 
                [] -> parse q env input 
                [(env, v, out)]-> [(env, v, out)])
```

As soon as I compile with Stack (stack build; stack run;), I get these errors, for both empty and <|> operators:

```
`empty' is not a (visible) method of class `Alternative'
`<|>' is not a (visible) method of class `Alternative'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include a [mre] so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Aplet123 post updated

Comment: The lines defining `empty` and `(<>)` are subordinate to the "instance" line. So shouldn't they be more indented to the right ? Remember an empty instance is legal in Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `empty` and `<|>` in order to implement them:

```hs
import Control.Applicative (Alternative, empty, (<|>))
```

Alternatively, it's possible to avoid bringing them into scope by importing `Control.Applicative` as qualified as well:

```hs
import Control.Applicative (Alternative)
import qualified Control.Applicative
```

Comment: When importing a typeclass, it’s also common to group the members with the class name, either with a wildcard import like `Alternative(..)`, or listing the names explicitly like `Alternative((<|>), empty)`. When importing a module qualified, it’s also typical to introduce an alias, often based on the final component of the name (e.g. `import qualified Control.Applicative as Applicative; import qualified Data.Text as Text`) or an abbreviated mnemonic (`import qualified Data.Foldable as F; import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL`).

Comment: @JonPurdy In this case, the qualified import is solely for the purpose of bringing its associated functions into scope, so I'd say an alias isn't necessary.

Comment: I agree, just adding more context. The pattern you’ve described is less common in my experience, I assume because in practice a module that defines an instance often wants to *use* the methods too. Importing a module qualified like this only brings methods into scope unqualified for method definitions, so e.g. `newtype Wrap f a = Wrap (f a); instance (Alternative f) => Alternative (Wrap f) where { empty = Wrap empty }` wouldn’t work, since the second `empty` isn’t in scope.

Comment: Haskell beginner here. I've seen functions being qualified with `T.pack`, but how's `import qualified Control.Applicative` different from just `import Control.Applicative`? No alias is used so, what's the qualification doing?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar `import qualified Control.Applicative` uses `Control.Applicative` as the qualifier, e.g. you would type in `Control.Applicative.empty`.